# Getting Distinct Values in SOQL Query

Tags: soql

I need to provide a query that gives me the latest StageName from the Opportunity object sofar I have tried this by writing a query for OpportunityHistory and the OpportunityFieldHistory. The thing is that when an Opportunity goes through more than one stage update in one day we need to provide only the latest Stage update. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Query the latest `StageName` from the **Opportunity** object to use the **OpportunityFieldHistory** object, which tracks the history of changes for the `StageName` field. You can use a `SOQL` query that filters by the **OpportunityId**, the **Field** name, and the **CreatedDate**, and then sorts by the **CreatedDate** in descending order.

For example:

```
Id oppId = '0063h00000D4uP8AAJ'; // Replace this with the your OpportunityId
List<OpportunityFieldHistory> oppFieldHistories = [SELECT Id, OldValue, NewValue, CreatedDate
                                                   FROM OpportunityFieldHistory
                                                   WHERE OpportunityId = :oppId
                                                   AND Field = 'StageName'
                                                   ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                                                   LIMIT 1];

if (!oppFieldHistories.isEmpty()) {
        OpportunityFieldHistory oppFieldHistory = oppFieldHistories[0];
        String latestStageName = (String) oppFieldHistory.NewValue;
        System.debug(latestStageName);
}
```

This query will return the most recent change for the `StageName` field for a given **OpportunityId**. If you want to query the latest `StageName` for multiple **OpportunityIds**, you can use a list or a set to store the **OpportunityIds** and use the **IN** operator in the **WHERE** clause.

For example:

```
List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>{'0063h00000D4uP8AAJ', '0063h00000D4uP9AAJ'}; // Replace this with the your OpportunityIds
List<OpportunityFieldHistory> oppFieldHistories = [SELECT Id, OpportunityId, OldValue, NewValue, CreatedDate
                                                   FROM OpportunityFieldHistory
                                                   WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppIds
                                                   AND Field = 'StageName'
                                                   ORDER BY OpportunityId, CreatedDate DESC];

Map<Id, String> oppIdStageNameMap = new Map<Id, String>();
for (OpportunityFieldHistory oppFieldHistory : oppFieldHistories) {
        Id oppId = oppFieldHistory.OpportunityId;
        String latestStageName = (String) oppFieldHistory.NewValue;
        if (!oppIdStageNameMap.containsKey(oppId)) {
                oppIdStageNameMap.put(oppId, latestStageName);
        }
}

for (Id oppId : oppIdStageNameMap.keySet()) {
        String latestStageName = oppIdStageNameMap.get(oppId);
        System.debug('OpportunityId: ' + oppId + ', Latest StageName: ' + latestStageName);
}
```

This query will return the latest `StageName` for each **OpportunityId** in the list or set, and store them in a map. You can then use the map to access the latest `StageName` for any **OpportunityId**.